# mocha: Testing whether something takes *more* than an interval of time

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

If you want to test that something takes under a certain amount of time, you can use the `.timeout()` function:

```
it('should have preloaded the first image', function () {
  this.timeout(10);

  return promise.then(function (data) {
    return Monkey.helpers.preload(data.urls[0]);
  });
});
```

However, it's not quite so easy to test the other way round: if I want to test whether a task takes *more* than 30ms, I have to use a timeout:

```
it('should not have preloaded the tenth image', function (cb) {
  return promise.then(function (data) {
    var finished = false;
    Monkey.helpers.preload(data.urls[10])
      .then(function () {
        finished = true;
      })

    setTimeout(function () {
      finished.should.be.False;
      cb();
    }, 30);
  });
});
```

This isn't very simple! I would much prefer something like this:

```
it('should not have preloaded the tenth image', function (cb) {
  this.shouldTake(30);

  return promise.then(function (data) {
    return Monkey.helpers.preload(data.urls[10]);
  });
});
```

Anyone know of a simpler way to do this?

Comment: So what's the question?